# Why isn't this dynamic VisualForce page style toggling the Static Resources properly?

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, controller-extension, apex, static-resources, dynamic-style

I'm currently looking at the [Dynamic References to Static Resources Using](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_resource.htm)

Mostly, it works as expected, with one anomaly:

When the page initially displays, as expected, it correctly uses both the THEME_BW/styles/style.css and the THEME_BW/images/logo.jpg.

When I select THEME_COLOR, it correctly changes both the style.css and the logo.jpg.

When I reselect THEME_BW, it correctly changes the logo.jpg back to the THEME_BW logo, *HOWEVER* the style remains the THEME_COLOR style.

This defect occurs in both Chrome and Firefox.

Here is my controller code:

```
public class VF_ThemeHandlerVFCtrlExt 
{
    public VF_ThemeHandlerVFCtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardController standardController){}

    public static Set<String> getAvailableThemeSet()
    {
        // You must have at least one uploaded static resource or this code will fail.
        // List their names here.
        return (new Set<String>{'Theme_Color', 'Theme_BW'});
    }

    public static List<SelectOption> getThemeOptionList()
    {
        List<SelectOption> themeSelectOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (String themeName : getAvailableThemeSet())
        {
            themeSelectOptionList.add(new SelectOption(themeName, themeName));
        }
        return themeSelectOptionList;
    }

    public String selectedTheme
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == selectedTheme)                      // Ensure we always have a theme
            { 
                selectedTheme = new List<String>(getAvailableThemeSet())[0];     
            } 
            return selectedTheme;
        }
        set
        {
            if (getAvailableThemeSet().contains(value)) { selectedTheme = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="VF_ThemeHandlerVFCtrlExt" showHeader="false">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="ThemePreview">
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource[selectedTheme], 'styles/styles.css')}" />
        <h1>Theme Viewer</h1>
        <p>You can select a theme to use while browsing this site.</p>

        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Select Theme: " for="themesList" />
            <apex:selectList id="themesList" size="1" value="{!selectedTheme}" >
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="ThemePreview" />
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!themeOptionList}" />
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <div class="custom" style="padding: 1em;"><!-- Begin Theme CSS hook -->
                <h2>This is a Sub-Heading</h2>
                  <p>
                      This is standard body copy. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
                      adipiscing elit. Quisque neque arcu, pellentesque in vehicula vitae, dictum 
                      id dolor. Cras viverra consequat neque eu gravida. Morbi hendrerit lobortis 
                      mauris, id sollicitudin dui rhoncus nec.
                  </p>
                  <p>
                      <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource[selectedTheme], 'images/logo.jpg')}" />
                  </p>
            </div>                                    <!-- End   Theme CSS hook -->
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your browser's "View Source", you will see that Visualforce pulls `apex:stylesheet` stylesheets up into the head section of the page.

If you use the raw HTML `<link rel="stylesheet" href="..."/>` instead, that remains in the page where you place it, in your case within the "ThemePreview" part of the page that you re-render. Try that.

Comment: This works perfectly!  One question though:  Given your explanation, why did the original version change the stylesheet the first time I made the selection?

Comment: @BrianKessler I'm afraid I have no idea...